# jquery check previous check-box before a tag to be checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code like

```
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="A" class="chbx">
<a href="#" class="checkbox-selector">href1</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="b" class="chbx">
<a href="#" class="checkbox-selector">href2</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="c" class="chbx">
<a href="#" class="checkbox-selector">href3</a>
```

What I desired is when I click on `href1` checkbox 1st should be selected and when I click on `href2`, the 2nd checkbox should be selected.

How can this be done in jQuery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
$('.checkbox-selector').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: As if jQuery 1.6+, you should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` for element properties. It would make your answer very similar to scessor's, but never mind. Right now, changing the HTML attribute will trigger the property change as well so it shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: can i also get the checkbox name that is checked ?

Comment: sure you can $('.checkbox-selector').click(function() {
    var element = $(this).prev();
    element.attr('checked', true);
    alert(element.attr('name'));
or you can use the .prop() as Fabricio said
});

Comment: `.prop()` is used to retrieve and set JS properties which are dynamic (such as `checked` state, `selectedIndex` etc), now for `name` you can safely use either `attr` or `prop`. You probably won't change the `name` property of an element, so you have no problem retrieving the html attribute `name`. I just think that OP meant to retrieve the link's text instead of the name, as all 3 checkboxes have the same name. `=]`

Comment: Yes I noticed that all checkboxes with the same name but I think chicharito wrote it for the example. any way chicharito you can get the links text by `$(this).html()` or the checkbox value by `element.val()`

Answer (score 2):

You could go about this in a different way and not use javascript at all

Try this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" value="hello" name="chkbox1" /> Here is the text</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" value="hello" name="chkbox2" /> Here is the text</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" value="hello" name="chkbox3" /> Here is the text</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery. You can use plain old html...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="chk1" value="A" class="chbx">
<label for="chk1" class="checkbox-selector">href1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="chk2" value="b" class="chbx">
<label for="chk2" class="checkbox-selector">href2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" id="chk3" value="c" class="chbx">
<label for="chk3" class="checkbox-selector">href3</label>
```

To add support to older browsers (e.g. ie6 suggested by Fabricio) use the jQuery approach suggested by scessor:

```
$('.checkbox-selector').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().prop('checked', true);
});
```

Note that you should implement both and only enable the javscript approach if you're using a browser that doesn't support labels.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a label, it will automatically check the checkbox for you as long as you give the checkbox an ID and set the FOR attribute in the label.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="A" class="chbx" id="c1">
<label for="c1" class="checkbox-selector">href1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="b" class="chbx" id="c2">
<label for="c2" class="checkbox-selector">href2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="abc" value="c" class="chbx" id="c3">
<label for="c3" class="checkbox-selector">href3</label>
```

Any styles you applied to the former hyperlink should still apply to the label.

Comment: will this work for all browser i.e i6 and above and chrome firefox ?

Comment: It should, this is pretty standard HTML.  Note that the version in which  label surrounds the input [may not work in IE6](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/html-label-toggle-select-fields/), so you may want to stick to keeping the label outside the input as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Fully working example which checks and unchecks the boxes on click:

```
$('.checkbox-selector').click(function() {
    var chb = $(this).prev(); //caches selector
    chb.prop('checked', !chb.prop('checked')); //inverses checked state
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2erJv/)

But honestly, unless you really need compatibility with older browsers such as ie6 and other non-html5 browsers, you should use the `<label>`s method.

---

If by `name` you meant the link's description, just use `$(this).text()` to get the clicked link's text.
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2erJv/2/)